# method for calculate possibility

Tags: python-3.x, math, methods

if i have two machine to predict the object is Dog or Cat or Horse.

first machine say : [0.3, 0.6, 0.1]

second machine say : [0.5, 0.2, 0.3 ]

for each category.

Is there a method to combine these two possibility list to get the most possible answer?

Comment: So what happens if the two machines predict different objects?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get the max values in those list:

```
first_machine= [0.3, 0.6, 0.1]
second_machine=[0.5, 0.2, 0.3 ]
answer=[max(first, second) for first,second in zip(first_machine, second_machine)]

>>>In []: answer
>>>Out[]: [0.5, 0.6, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have one machine that will display Dog, Cat, or Horse with these probabilities: 0.3, 0.6, 0.1

Then you have a second machine that does the same but with these probabilities: 0.5, 0.2, 0.3

If you were to use both machines at the same time, you would see two values displayed. After using both machines 1,000 times, you could tally up the number of times you saw each animal and calculate the approximate probability that an animal would show up in a continuous stream of animals displayed by both machines. You would find that the new probabilities would be an average of your original probabilities.

```
>>> machine_1 = 0.3, 0.6, 0.1
>>> round(sum(machine_1), 3)
1.0
>>> machine_2 = 0.5, 0.2, 0.3
>>> round(sum(machine_2), 3)
1.0
>>> import statistics
>>> average = tuple(map(statistics.mean, zip(machine_1, machine_2)))
>>> round(sum(average), 3)
1.0
>>> average
(0.4, 0.4, 0.2)
>>>
```